# OpenCMS 10.0.0 and Jboss EAP 7.0.0.GA malformed Uri in CmsDefaultLinkSubstitutionHandler

Tags: java, exception, jboss, jboss7.x, opencms

I would like to install an **OpenCMS 10.0.0** to a **Jboss EAP 7.0.0.GA**, and I could do the setup, and I can log in with Admin user, I see explorer and other, but when I would like to see the http://localhost:8080/opencms/opencms/overview/ I get this exception what I found in C:\ [jboss.home]\standalone\deployments\opencms.war\WEB-INF\logs\opencms.log :

```
10 okt. 2016 15:25:55,687  WARN [DefaultLinkSubstitutionHandler: 428] Could not resolve the site path of malformed Uri "C:[jboss.home]\standalone\deployments\opencms.war/opencms/handleStatic/gwt/opencms/C2E676F52806BF5F39736A511DB5B2D9.gwt.rpc"
    java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\ [jboss.home]\standalone\deployments\opencms.war/opencms/handleStatic/gwt/opencms/C2E676F52806BF5F39736A511DB5B2D9.gwt.rpc
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3058)
        at java.net.URI.(URI.java:588)
        at org.opencms.staticexport.CmsDefaultLinkSubstitutionHandler.getSimpleRootPath(CmsDefaultLinkSubstitutionHandler.java:423)
        at org.opencms.staticexport.CmsDefaultLinkSubstitutionHandler.getRootPath(CmsDefaultLinkSubstitutionHandler.java:393)
        at org.opencms.staticexport.CmsLinkManager.getRootPath(CmsLinkManager.java:482)
        at org.opencms.staticexport.CmsLinkManager.getRootPath(CmsLinkManager.java:444)
        at org.opencms.gwt.CmsGwtServiceContext.getSerializationPolicy(CmsGwtServiceContext.java:248)
        at org.opencms.gwt.CmsGwtServiceContext.getSerializationPolicy(CmsGwtServiceContext.java:186)
        at org.opencms.gwt.CmsGwtService.doGetSerializationPolicy(CmsGwtService.java:276)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.getSerializationPolicy(RemoteServiceServlet.java:234)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamReader.prepareToRead(ServerSerializationStreamReader.java:505)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:240)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:296)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.opencms.gwt.CmsGwtService.service(CmsGwtService.java:194)
        at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.invokeGwtService(OpenCmsCore.java:1701)
        at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsServlet.doGet(OpenCmsServlet.java:156)
        at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsServlet.doPost(OpenCmsServlet.java:175)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:792)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

PS.: In jboss.home, there are no whitespace or other spcial chars. **I think the problem is the URI not start with file: , but the question is how can I solve this problem?**

Comment: aren't you missing any `%` somewhere in your config? A whitespace too much? I'm surprised about that surfacing address `c:\ [jboss.home]\ ...`

Comment: @Alberto: There are no white space in the path. The same installing is working on tomcat, so this is the reasen why I don't understand what is the problem. By the way, the full path is "C:\DATA\PROJECT\OPENCMS\jboss\standalone\opencms.war\..." .

Comment: Sorry for stating the obvious, but that URI is clearly malformed: `C:[jboss.home]\standalone\deployments\opencms.war/opencms/handleStatic/...`. I don't have a JBoss, but I doubt that it messes with the logs, so I have to assume that OpenCms tries to invoke literally that URI. There are visibly two problems with the URI: 1) the `C:[jboss.home]` isn't a valid URI constituent, as long as I'm aware; 2) the '\' (backslashes) aren't path separators neither. It looks as if you had the site configuration broken. But be aware that I don't have windows nor jboss: I'm not saying that there isn't a bug.